# How to Line Break or new line in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am having hard time to match Special characters set in XAML. I only on the following:

To represent a LineBreak in XAML hyperlink button:

use : > lineBreak <

But What do I use to represent a New Line or LineBreak In XAML hyperlink button??

Example : I want this one line mag : This is line one. This is line two

into this :

This is line one. This is line two.

it seems this \r\n is not working. This is line one \r\n

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You've got options. For example;

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Line One&#10;Line Two"/>
```

or

```
<HyperlinkButton>
  <HyperlinkButton.Content>
    <TextBlock>
      <Run Text="Line 1"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="Line 2"/>
    </TextBlock>
  </HyperlinkButton.Content>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

Hope this helps.

Addendum: You can do this stuff in basically anything. WPF, Silverlight, UWP, whatever. It's not WP specific.

Comment: +1 for `<LineBreak/>`. Expecting our translators to know what to do with `&#10` will result in nothing but heartache.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [preserve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788720.aspx). It includes *all* whitespace, so inputting the exact string you want would involve messing up your indentation, but this will work:

```
        <HyperlinkButton xml:space="preserve">This is line one.
This is line two.</HyperlinkButton>
```

Comment: 'Unexpected 'ATTRIBUTE' in parse rule 'NonemptyPropertyElement ::= . PROPERTYELEMENT Content? ENDTAG.'.' Line number '14' and line position '33'.   I Got above error with xml:space="preserve".  how this can be resolved.?

Comment: You sir, are a ninja.  Minimal input with maximum result.

Comment: This is very useful as it can also be used on other display elements such as `TEXTBLOCK`

Comment: This worked well for me, if you have to extract text later is very useful.